# Weird bug in Chrome and Safari OS X 10.9, hover over link drops to next line, WPfolio Two

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, safari, osx-mavericks

I should start by saying I'm no expert when it comes to code and web design. That said, I have recently upgraded to OS X 10.9 Mavericks. After updating I'm experiencing a weird bug, specifically on my website and others like it using the wordpress theme WPfolio Two. When you hover over a link, the link jumps and drops to the next line. As soon as you move your mouse away from the linked text the text link hops back up to the line it's supposed to be on. This only happens using Chrome or Safari, it does not seem to happen in Firefox. For an example hover over any link on on either of these two pages http://jasonirla.com/category/news/ or http://notlaura.com/wpfolio-two/read-me/ Thie bug does not seem to effect drop down navigation menus or some (but not all) links in sidebar widget menus.

The bug makes it practically impossible to click the jumping link. I'm not experienced enough to say if this is a browser bug, a OS X bug, a problem with the code in the wordpress them I'm using or what. I am comfortable editing and writing small additions to the theme code using a child theme CSS but in this instance I have no idea where to start or what I'm looking for (to fix). All I know is that this problem did not occur when I was still running 10.8 mountain lion on my mac.

If anyone has any experience with problem like the one I'm experiencing and could offer me some advice I'd really appreciate any help you can offer. I've been searching all over for a week now and haven't been able to find any answers and nothing I've tried seems to make a difference. Thank you for any help or advice you are able to offer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave a comment, so I hope this will help you:

- Check your font-style on this hover link, is it bold on hover?
- Do you use another font-size on hover?
- Do you use a iOS compatible font on hover? (using a font that only works on windows systems will be transformed on iOS devices and could cause this bug.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking into your suggestions. As of now I don't see any of the conflicts you mention. The font size and weight seem to be consistent--but it's a complicated theme with imported style libraries that I'm still going through. The font itself is pretty safe from what I can tell, helvetica which then defaults to arial etc. A pretty old standard from what I know so I think it should be ios7 compatible. I'll keep looking. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I was contacted by the designer of the WP theme (WPfolio Two), there's a style on 193 of the CSS "display:compact" which is the problem. I put block comments around that line /* display:compact */ and the bug is fixed. Thanks for the initial help @lickmycode – user1544398 just now edit